# sql copy data in column from one row to all others

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an SQL table with a column that I need to copy the data from one specific row to all other rows.  How can do this?

ie: update TABLE set ALL OTHER ROWS IN COLUMN = to ROW1 WHERE COLUMN2 = UNIQUE IDENTIFIER. I hope this makes sense.

Data example of table USER:

```
CODE     PASS        
Joe      Degree1
Sue      Degree2
Pat      Degree3
```

Basically, I want to take the Data in column PASS from JOE and copy it to all other users (SUE and PAT), so when said and done, PASS should equal "Degree1" for all three users.

Comment: put sample data and your required output..that will make sense

Comment: Can you please give schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @updatevalue <yourcolumndatatype>
SELECT @updatevalue = updatecolumn
FROM yourtable
WHERE uniquecolumn = uniqueidentifier

UPDATE yourtable
SET updatecolumn = @updatevalue
WHERE uniquecolumn <> uniqueidentifier
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @UNIQUEIDENTIFIER INT = 1 --For examnple type of UniqueColumn is INT
UPDATE TableName SET 
ColumnToUpdate = (SELECT ColumnToUpdate WHERE UniqueColumn = @UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
WHERE UniqueColumn <> @UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
```

Comment: Hi Fabio, I receive this error: Must declare the scalar variable.

Comment: You need to declare a variable(check updated answer) or replace `@UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` with your unique identifier value

Answer (score 0):

**Table_1**

```
key  specData

 1       a

 2    null

 3    null

 4    null
```

**Query**

```
UPDATE Table_1 t
SET t.specData= (SELECT specData FROM Table_1 WHERE key = 1)
WHERE key <> 1;
```

Hope it help you!